# Including an array inside PHP JSON

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have created a JSON in PHP as follows

```
$result=mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT * FROM service_provide WHERE personal_id='".$personal_id."'") or die(mysqli_error($mysqli);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
{



  $data[] = array(
    ' fname'   => $row['fname'],   
      ' email_id'   => $row['email_id'], 
      ' phone_number'   => $row['phone_number'],
      ' state'   => $row['state'],
      ' city'   => $row['city'],
      ' main_id'   => $row['main_id'],
      ' sub_id'   => $row['sub_id'],
      ' service_id'   => $row['service_id'],
      'portfolio1'  => $row['portfolio1'],
      'portfolio2'  => $row['portfolio2'],
      'portfolio3'  => $row['portfolio3'],
  );


    }
      $json = json_encode($data);
      echo  $json;
```

Now I have another array in PHP that I want to include to the above JSON. The array is as follows.

```
      $service_title=array();
$result5=mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT * FROM request_submission WHERE       req_personal_id='".$req."'") or die(mysqli_error($mysqli);  

    while($row5 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result5))

    {
        $service_title[]=$row5["service_title"];


    }
```

How do in insert the above array into the PHP JSON I mentioned above?

Comment: Just insert it, just like any of the other variables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two array. 1. `$data` and 2. `$service_title`.

so you can use  `array_merge()` php function and convert new array in to json.

something like this.

```
$result = array_merge($data, $service_title);
$json = json_encode($result);
echo  $json;
```

Comment: I am not sure how the resultant JSON would look like. Would you show me how?

Comment: I've take `array_merge()` example from this site http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php. and convert that in to json using json_encode(). so now my json output look like `{"color":"green","0":2,"1":4,"2":"a","3":"b","shape":"trapezoid","4":4}` this.hope this help you